# Query returing no results codename one

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone

Query showing no results and not giving any error .control not entering inside the if block help me out that where is the mistake i am doing ?
i have tried many ways to get the result but all in vain. When i tried the following  before the if statement

```
int column=cur.getColumnCount();
Row row=cur.getRow();
row.getString(0);
```

then i got the resultset closed exception

```
Database db=null;
Cursor cur=null;
System.out.print("Printing from accounts class "+Email+Password);
String [] param={Email,Password};
System.out.print(param[0]+param[1]);

try{
  db=Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("UserAccountsDB.db");
 cur= db.executeQuery("select * from APPUserInfo WHERE Email=? AND Password=?",(String [])param);
int   columns=cur.getColumnCount();
if(columns > 0) {

   boolean next = cur.next();
    while(next) {
      Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
      String LoggedUserName=currentRow.getString(0);
      String LoggedUserPassword=currentRow.getString(1);
      System.out.println(LoggedUserName);
      next = cur.next();
     }

   }
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
   Util.cleanup(db);
   Util.cleanup(cur);
   Log.e(ex);
     }

   finally{
     Util.cleanup(db);
    Util.cleanup(cur);

     }
```

Comment: Are you able to get any result by hitting db directly?

Comment: try by putting the line "boolean next = cur.next();" before  "int   columns=cur.getColumnCount();"

Comment: columnCount () returns 6 but whenever at line " boolean next=cur.next()" it returns false and doesn't enter the while loop and before the while loop i have tried to get the row then the following exception raised

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
 at org.sqlite.RS.checkOpen(RS.java:84)
 at org.sqlite.RS.markCol(RS.java:111)
 at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:562)
 at com.codename1.impl.javase.SECursor.getString(SECursor.java:266)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.Accounts.AccountsDB.getLoggedInUserInfo(AccountsDB.java:46)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.TableLayoutDemo.lambda$AccountLogin$5(TableLayoutDemo.java:199)
 at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
 at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:411)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jobin said in the comments the cursor to the result appears before the first entry so until you invoke `next()` for the first time you don't have access to the data.

It seems that the table is empty which means there is no user in the DB matching email/password. Try removing the email/password clause to get a list of all the users to verify.

Comment: yep @shai almog thanks i have error i my table columns